# The best way to compare two very large lists

Tags: java, performance, list, collections, comparison

I have two very large lists. Let say a few millions of elements. Both list are already sorted in the same way. Now I need to check that both lists are equal.
What is the best way to do this? 
For now my idea is to compare line to line using Assert.assertEquals.

```
for(int i=0;i<Math.max(list1.size(),list2.size()),i++){

Assert.assertEquals(list1.get(i),list2.get(i));
}
```

Unfortunately I'm worry about the performance of this solution if the lists have many millions of objects. Additionally if the lists are not equal then I need to know where the discrepancies are.

Is there a better, faster and confident solution to do this?

Comment: Is it ArrayList or LinkedList?

Comment: @RajuSharma ArrayList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end it's an O(n) operation if the lists are equal. So I would go the easy way and simply use:

```
Assert.assertEquals(list1, list2);
```

which will rely on `List::equals` to compare the lists - I doubt you can be more efficient than that, unless you have specific information about the list content.

If the lists are not equal you should get an exception that shows the difference.

Comment: *If the lists are not equal you should get an exception that shows the difference.* clever clever :)

Comment: Out of the many answers the only one that makes real sense (imho).

Comment: The one thing missing... You might want to mention the preconditions that are required to make the assert working. Maybe not required for the OP but for future readers.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, what preconditions?

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to do this can be to pivot on the size of the list, which you anyway are using:

```
if(list1.size() > list2.size()) {
    list1.removeAll(list2);
    // print the list1 (discrepancies)
    Assert.fail("Lists are not equal");
} else if
...// same for list2.size() > list1.size()
} else {
    list1.removeAll(list2);
     if(!list1.isEmpty()) { 
        // print the discrepancies
        Assert.fail("Lists are not equal");
     } 
}
```

Comment: He is mainly asking about performance. Your code does a lot of stuff under the covers. Not sure how helpful this is.

Answer (score 1):

The performance would mainly depend on the Collection **class**  and the **method** you would be using to perform it.

As you mentioned your code, it is iterating and comparing using **get** method of list, we would need to know which collection class which implements list has better performance for **get** method..

```
for(int i=0;i<Math.max(list1.size(),list2.size()),i++){
    Assert.assertEquals(list1.get(i),list2.get(i));
}
```

If you are using **List** implemented **LinkedList** get method then the performance order for fetching a single object will be **O(n/4) average**.

If you are using **List** implemented **ArrayList**  get method then the performance order for fetching a single object will be **O(1)**.

So, we can say the comparison based on your code will be faster for **ArrayList** .

Comment: *ArrayList get method then the performance order will be O(1).* overall?

Comment: @nullpointer Yes, the get method of List which implements ArrayList will have better performance than, a List which implements LinkedList

Comment: Not talking about comparisons here but the overall order wouldn't be `O(1)` even if we do a `get` on `ArrayList`.

Comment: @nullpointer, I was saying in for single fetch.. and i did modify the same

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple: when you want to be sure that two lists are equal - you have to compare them elementwise. Of course you only do that when both lists have equal size.

Thus you always deal with O(n).

And Java ArrayLists are already a good choice as data structure.

The only potential optimization: this problem can be solved faster by using multiple threads comparing sub lists. So parallelStream() could be your friend here.

Alternatively - when the lists contain int, double... primitive values - then you could consider using plain old arrays instead of collection based Lists.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you must have realised by now that you don't need to do this:

```
i < Math.max(list1.size(),list2.size())
```

The 2 lists can be equal only if their sizes are equal.

Since the lists are already sorted, the already suggested way is the best way to compare with a little modification:

```
Assert.equals(list1.size(), list2.size())
for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(), i++){
   Assert.assertEquals(list1.get(i),list2.get(i));
}
```

This will give O(n) time complexity.

I think we should avoid `list1.equals(list2)` for `ArrayList` coz it checks for the size equality in the end once all the elements from the shorter list are visited.

One minor suggestion, always use indentation and spaces at right places. It makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You should stored them in a binary tree. Searching is really fast when compares to a list.

Comment: Nonsense. He is asking how to efficiently compare two large lists. Turning them into trees does not help with that at all.